# Java class not found in Jackson

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and have a program that's throwing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
    at ExtractCustomerIds.main(ExtractCustomerIds.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:366)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoaders.java:184)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoader.java:419)
    ... 1 more
```

I know the problem has to be with paths, classpath or jar name, but I can't figure out as of now.

My folder structure is:

```
.
 - get_customer_ids
   - ExtractCustomerIds.java
 - libs
   - jackson-all-1.9.11.jar
```

So when I'm inside the `get_customer_ids` I give the following command:

`get_customer_ids$ javac -cp ../libs/* ExtractCustomerIds.java` and this causes the error above.

I thought I was setting the classpath correctly, but it's still not working. What's missing?

Comment: Add `jackson-mapper-asl` jar to your classpath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception occurs when **running** your program - you are specifying the classpath while **compiling**. The classpath set during compilation is not stored inside the compiled class files or the like - you need to correctly specify it when running your program, too!

Like so:

```
$ java -cp ../libs/* ExtractCustomerIds
```

Comment: edited your answer to add the actual java invocation command that will be needed.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot! and of course, makes a lot of sense to pass the classpath to `java` too. :-)